# ListView recycling virtualization performance with variable item's size

Tags: wpf, performance, listview, layout

Using ListView with thousands of items like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                 VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
                 VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                 VirtualizingPanel.CacheLength="1,1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:ItemUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I found scrolling to be extremely slow if I cause every item to have different heights in `ItemUserControl`. While scrolling fast by dragging the thumb, each frame takes around **200-250 ms** just to layout.

If I change `VirtualizationMode` to `Standard` it goes down to 70-110 ms.
If I additionally change `ScrollUnit` to `Item` it goes down to 30-70 ms.
But if I keep everything as before and simply force every item to be the same `Height`, it goes down to **5-7 ms**.

Additionally I found that the scrolling with different heights is faster when scrolling around the top of the list and lot slower at the bottom.

My guess is that when reused `ItemUserControl` has its `Height` changed, it causes layout update for whole `ListView`. Although that doesn't really explain why it performs better at the beginning than at the end. I also find such speed difference a bit hard to believe.

Anyone has more insight into WPF's layout system and could explain why this is happening? Maybe a solution to achieve <10ms layout times with variable heights?

Comment: Just checking - did you set the ListView's <ListView.ItemsPanel> as a VirtualizingStackPanel ?

Comment: @DeanChalk thanks for sanity checking, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1 the default is already VirtualizingStackPanel. The virtualization works fine, it's just too slow when scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DeanChalk for questioning my sanity, which led me to question WPF's sanity, which led to this answer.

It turns out that while `ListView` has issues with different sizes of items, `ItemsControl` does not. `ListView` inherits from `ItemsControl`, but there must be something which causes the issues.

So using `ItemsControl` is the answer.

This code will enable virtualization for `ItemsControl` and, using the same metric as before, performed at around 20 ms for layout when scrolling fast.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
              VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
              VirtualizingPanel.CacheLength="1,1"
              VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:ItemUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

It still seems slower than it probably could be, but it's usable.
The speed difference when scrolling around the top vs the bottom is still there and I can't really explain it. If anyone has some insight, please do comment.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, where my item's height is not the same. I've tried VirtualizationMode="Recycling" but it does not work. When I scroll up and down, I see that my item's height is not as expected. What should be short becomes tall, and vice versa

Comment: @DhinneshJeevan I don't remember what else I did, but this code here should work. The only additional thing I see in my code is using custom ItemsControl class that disables caching of sizes, but rather provides it directly when requested (because I can calculate it faster).

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to the math required to size/position the scroll position.

A) If the items are all fixed size, and scrolling is by Pixel:

- Scroll Height = Items.Count * Item.Height
- First Visible Item = Scroll Offset (Pixels) / Item.Height

B) If the items are variable height, but the scrolling is by Item:

- Scroll Height = Items.Count
- First Visible Item = Scroll Offset (Items)

C) If the items are variable height, and the scrolling is by Pixel:

- Scroll Height = Sum of Item.Height for all items
- First Visible Item = Scroll Offset (Pixels) - Height of first N items; must search for N.

There are some optimizations that can be done for choice C and may or may not be built into WPF:

- Scroll Height could be approximated rather than being accurate.  Maybe use an average item height for items that have been measured so far.
- First Visible Item calculation could be done with a binary search, but still may require actually measuring all items above the first visible item.

Basically, behavior C will always be a worst-case-scenario for virtualizing your item list, because it will likely need to load all of the items anyway, just to do the layout measurements.